# How can I recover Ubuntu 12.04 when Grub can't find it?

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2

I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 a couple of months ago, and haven't done anything special since.  No dual boot installation or anything of the like, and I'm running a 32 bit machine.  This morning tracks started slipping in Rhythmbox, and I realized that the sound of Youtube videos was similarly slipping.  I decided to reboot, but I was booted into Ubuntu 11.10 which I can't log into at all as it just crashes immediately(basically just freezes up).

There is no Ubuntu 12.04(Linux kernel 3.02) option on my boot menu, I even tried to do a boot-repair which stated that everything ran successfully.  It's as if Ubuntu 12.04 disappeared from my machine.

Is there any way to recover my 12.04 installation?

EDIT:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00050194

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   952197119   476097536   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       952199166   976771071    12285953    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       952199168   976771071    12285952   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

EDIT2:

Ok I tried to recover Grub2 again, Ubuntu 12.04 with Linux kernel 3.2.0 is nowhere to be found in my newly created grub.cfg file.  When I mount /dev/sda1 however I can see all my files.

EDIT3:

When I boot using a live cd, and chroot, I get the following from the terminal:

```
root@ubuntu:/# cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=11.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=oneiric
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 11.10"
```

EDIT4:

Can't seem to find the Linux kernel version for Ubuntu 12.04 either.

```
root@ubuntu:/# dpkg -l | grep "linux\-[a-z]*\-"
ii  linux-generic-pae        3.0.0.29.33   Complete Generic Linux kernel
ii  linux-headers-3.0.0-29   3.0.0-29.46   Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.0.0
ii  linux-headers-3.0.0-29-generic-pae  3.0.0-29.46 Linux kernel headers for version 3.0.0 on x86
ii  linux-headers-generic-pae           3.0.0.29.33 Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-image-2.6.35-22-generic-pae   2.6.35-22.33  Linux kernel image for version 2.6.35 on x86
rc  linux-image-2.6.38-10-generic-pae   2.6.38-10.46  Linux kernel image for version 2.6.38 on x86
rc  linux-image-2.6.38-11-generic-pae   2.6.38-11.50  Linux kernel image for version 2.6.38 on x86
rc  linux-image-2.6.38-12-generic-pae   2.6.38-12.51  Linux kernel image for version 2.6.38 on x86
rc  linux-image-2.6.38-13-generic-pae   2.6.38-13.57  Linux kernel image for version 2.6.38 on x86
rc  linux-image-2.6.38-14-generic-pae   2.6.38-14.58  Linux kernel image for version 2.6.38 on x86
rc  linux-image-2.6.38-15-generic-pae   2.6.38-15.66  Linux kernel image for version 2.6.38 on x86
ii  linux-image-2.6.38-16-generic-pae   2.6.38-16.67  Linux kernel image for version 2.6.38 on x86
rc  linux-image-2.6.38-8-generic-pae    2.6.38-8.42   Linux kernel image for version 2.6.38 on x86
ii  linux-image-3.0.0-29-generic-pae    3.0.0-29.46   Linux kernel image for version 3.0.0 on x86
ii  linux-image-generic-pae             3.0.0.29.33   Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-libc-dev                      3.0.0-29.46   Linux Kernel Headers for development
ii  linux-sound-base                    1.0.24+dfsg-0ubuntu2 base package for ALSA and OSS sound systems
```

Comment: You said you don't have dual boot but you booted into Ubuntu 11.10? Can you show the partitions that you have in the hard drive (with a Live CD/USB for example)?

Comment: Yea that's what is so strange, 11.10 shouldn't be on the machine at all anymore.

Comment: How is this possible?  How could Linux kernel 3.2 and Ubuntu 12.04 just vanish from my machine?

Comment: If you can see all your files, the best you can do is backup all of them, install Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS formatting all your hard drive and restoring your files.

Comment: any specific reason why this was downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do a full re-install of Ubuntu.  Still don't know how any of this is possible, my hard drive didn't fail and isn't corrupted.